# How to read file from PuTTY

Tags: putty

I have a mission to read information from some file with PuTTY.
please login to: '*somewhere*' there you will find a file named 'INSTUCTIONS' with instructions on how to proceed.
How i do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Putty is an SSH/Telnet client. What you want to do completely depends on the system you are connecting to. You could have a file prestaged in the home directory of the connecting SSH user which could then be opened through the Putty session.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're SSHing onto a unix box of some kind, use "ls" to browse the file structure.  Find the file, then use "cat".  e.g.:
cat INSTRUCTIONS.txt